# Open Report in Print Preview Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to open a report in print preview, from a form, but I am not sure where to put the function.

here is my code so far, could someone please point out what I need to add and where

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt_Tanc", acViewReport, WhereCondition:="[TMProfiling_ID]=" & Me!TMProfiling_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a vba Code:

You can create a command button and then write in the form on VBA like this:

```
Private Sub Command44_Click()

DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt_Tanc", acViewReport, WhereCondition:="[TMProfiling_ID]=" & Me!TMProfiling_ID

End Sub
```

You can access the Visual Basic menu by pressing ALT + F11

Then you can select your form, In my example it is named "Form_Menu"[image: Picture]

Please say if you need further explanations